# Water sometimes come up in my tub, but my drain is not clogged.I in a condo on first floor of 14 story high rise

Tags: bathtub

Dirty water backs up in my tub sometimes,but my drain is not clogged.I live in a condo on the first floor in a 14 story high rise

Comment: On the multi story buildings we built each floor had a back flow preventer so if the main line did plug the lower floors would not be flooded with the upper floors sewage. These were located in a utility closet at each floor, on occasion they need cleaning or sometimes when the upper floors drop water it backs up on the lower floors, I would check with your maintenance person this only takes a few minutes to clean but is a smelly nasty job so it usually only gets done when there is a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Clearly your drain is clogged, but below where your sink joins the main drain; it is not fully blocked however.

If enough people run their sinks/whatever hits that line, it fills up and backs up, and eventually it will hit your sink.